# How can I use OpenStreetMap in my Compact Framework App?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, openstreetmap

Does anyone know, how I can use OpenStreetMap inside my Compact Framework application? Is there a Framework or something like that? All I can find in their wiki is how to contribute to their project and to user their software to map data. But I want to use their maps to show the users location inside my own app. I could not find anything about using their web service or whatever I have to use to show their maps inside my application.

Comment: I'd like to know how you render the XML from OpenStreetMap into an actual image.

Answer (score 4):

There is a project on Google Code that wants to create a .NET library for the OpenStreetMap API. The website states that there currently is an alpha release, so it might be worth checking that out: [code.google.com/p/openstreetmapnet](http://code.google.com/p/openstreetmapnet)

And there are two similar projects on CodePlex as well:
[osmscout.codeplex.com](http://osmscout.codeplex.com)
[gmap4dotnet.codeplex.com](http://gmap4dotnet.codeplex.com)

Maybe those can be used in the Compact Framework as well, or you could ask the project teams to add that feature (or get involved yourself, it is opensource after all).

Comment: The OpenStreetMap.Net project hasn't been updated in long time.

Answer (score 1):

CloudMade provides APIs for embedding OpenStreetMap maps in many languages - but not .NET as of the time of writing. There are plain HTTP APIs for map tiles available that you could call from .NET programs, but this is of course fairly low-level.

The CloudMade APIs are designed for developers who want to embed OSM output in their projects, rather than the OSM API which is geared towards map creation, so I think you might be interested in the CloudMade stuff.

See http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects for more.

Answer (score 0):

They don't appear to have any CF libraries, but the [API specification is well documented](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API), so there's no reason you couldn't integrate with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a CF component that can download OpenStreetMap tiles, and also plot points of interest and basic routes. Depending on your requirements, and any restrictions on licences that you're permitted to use, then it may be of use to you?

Answer (score 0):

[Brutile](http://brutile.codeplex.com/) looks quite promising. It is a library designed for C# to connect to OpenStreetMap sources. (Silverlight demo available [Here](http://brutiledemo.appspot.com/).

The wiki also has a [listing of all .NET related pages](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Category:Microsoft.NET). Of the documented projects, [OpenStreetMapViewer](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenStreetMapViewer) looks like it fits your needs the best. It's designed to display a portion of OpenStreetMap within a .NET app. I'm sure at least one of these will work for windows mobile.