# Movable pictures on a map using .net compact framework 2.0 mobile device 5.0

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-5.0, compact-framework2.0

We need to find a way to create a movable (at run time) picture on a map overlay using the .net compact framework 2.0 on 5.0 mobile device.

The only choice we have seen so far is flash however given the hardware's limitations, I was thinking it might be slow. I want to know if anyone has any other ideas for what we could use to perform this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options.  Do it in native code and p/invoke it.  Or if you want to deal only in .NET CF you are going to have to write a custom control that handles all the painting.  If I were doing it and the map and picture were presented as Image objects I'd probably use a .NET custom control, and double buffer the blitting of the images.  If you actually have to perform the map rendering of primitives, you are probably better off using native code.  I know this is a bit high level, but so is your question.

This is a good start for information on custom .NET CF controls.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c632yz4(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Just saw this question too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922333/how-can-i-use-openstreetmap-in-my-compact-framework-app.  The libraries mentioned might have ways to do what you want you could adapt.

Comment: Thanks this is the starting place I am looking for.